# strcpy crashing when used with strrchr

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This code crash when calling strcpy. I have used this way in many places of my code to create a path. But this code fail only in one particular function always. What is the problem in this code.

```
char updaterPath[1024];
if(GetModuleFileName(NULL, updaterPath, 1024)==0)
{
    return 0;
}
char * temp=strrchr(updaterPath,'\\');
strcpy(temp,"\\ru.exe");
```

Comment: What did you discover when you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Did you check temp value? Are you sure it is not NULL?

Comment: Im using codeblocks. Its working fine when i ran in debug mode. But when only running in release mode program crashing. In release mode I cant use debugger

Comment: What happens if `updaterPath` does not contain a backslash? Try using `strchrnul()` instead.

Comment: @Damian temp not null

Comment: @markgz strchrnul() cant use in codeblocks.

Comment: Does it print an error message?  Have you considered reading it?

Comment: @stark No error message. Program just crashing.

Comment: Add a `printf("updaterPath: [%s]\n", updaterPath);` statement before declaring `temp`. I ran the code in _VC2k10_, and I didn't get the crash. `GetModuleFileNeme` returned the name and extension of my executable , preceded by a `\\`. I was able (as expected) to `strcpy` a longer string than the original.

Comment: What keeps you from debugging a Release configuration? Of course, optimizations do obscure some of the relationships between source code and object code, but debugging is still possible. To enhance the debugging experience for optimized builds, Visual Studio (starting with 2013) offers the [/Zo (Enhance Optimized Debugging)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785163.aspx) compiler option.

Comment: @IInspectable Im using codeblocks nightly version. It is skipping breakpoints and continue. I guess reason is no debugging symbols.

Comment: No, the reason is: Code::Blocks is a craptastic tool. Stop using it. I mean, using MBCS as the default character encoding? On Windows? In 2015? Time to move on to something less useless. Start [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. But it is lame and not make sense. My original code was like this

```
char updaterPath[1024];
    if(GetModuleFileName(NULL, updaterPath, 1024)==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
            if(RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\ddddd",0,NULL,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,NULL,&hKey,NULL)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                long res1=RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"version", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)regVersion, &regVersionLen);
                if(res1==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND||strcmp(regVersion,AutoVersion::FULLVERSION_STRING))          //check for version mismatch and go in
                {

                    char * temp = strrchr(updaterPath,'\\');
                    strcpy(temp+1,"Downloads\\ru.exe");
```

I changed it to this and now it is working fine

```
char updaterPath[1024];
    if(RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\\ddddd",0,NULL,0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,NULL,&hKey,NULL)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        long res1=RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"version", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)regVersion, &regVersionLen);
        if(res1==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND||strcmp(regVersion,AutoVersion::FULLVERSION_STRING))          //check for version mismatch and go in
        {
            if(GetModuleFileName(NULL, updaterPath, 1024)==0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            char * temp = strrchr(updaterPath,'\\');
            strcpy(temp+1,"Downloads\\ru.exe");
```

Comment: You probably have a buffer overflow in `regVersion` that is corrupting the `updaterPath` variable.

Comment: You should additionally verify that `updaterPath` has enough room left to store the string put into it by `strcpy`.

Comment: @MicroVirus In my case it is more than enough

Comment: @dilushan: You are calling `GetModuleFileName`. You have no control over the location, where the binary image resides on any given machine. You can safely assume, that this will corrupt memory sooner or later.